# Android 2D animation on characters

Tags: android, animation

I have created a character and I wonder how I have to animate it regarding the fact that :

- It has to move when on static position, I mean for example eyes blinking, mouth closing.
- It has to move on the screen regarding to player gesture.
- It has to be involved in collision.

I read about, AnimationDrawable, SurfaceView, Canvas ... but which way is the best ?

Thank very much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make a game you should consider [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) with [textures](http://www.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-vi-textures/).
[This](http://www.jayway.com/?s=openGL+ES) is a pretty good tutorial, though it contains a few coding errors, it makes the concept very clear!

The OpenGLES method would give much much more freedom, than animating Views, but maybe harder to master.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is still OK if it is a 2d game ?

Comment: It really depends on how big this game would be.If you're seriously considering game development in openGL I think openGL is a must. If this is just a simple school project, learning openGl may just over-complicate things.

-Either way learning openGL would not be wasted time. Try [this](http://www.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/) tutorial if you're interested!

Comment: Thank you YT. It is going to be a kind of puzzle game in which the goal is to make the main character going out of the level ( made of holes, walls, traps ... ). He will be helped by other characters with unique capacity, to help him dealing with the specificities of the level. Each characters just move in straight line, with finger gestures, until it uncounter an element. So, still openGL or not ?

Comment: Do you plan other games as well or just this one?
If you want to get into game development(taht means makin multiple apps), then I recommend openGL.

Comment: Hello Y.T. Joules, just that one !

Comment: Okay then you should not get into openGL, it's too complicated to learn just for one project.

Comment: Okay so it is AnimationDrawable, SurfaceView, Canvas , thank you very much Y.T

Comment: Read through these tutorials: [Displaying](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-displaying.html) and [Moving](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-moving-images.html) Images on the screen. He's using Canvas to achieve this.

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for ! By the way, do you also know tuto that explain how to move a character in a specific area of a screen made only from rows and columns. More specifically, make that the character can only move from the center of an area ( lets say row 3 column 4 ) to another one ? Do I need to set up an array ? Thank you again Y.T. I am starting to do nice things thanks to you !